# Long polling Kill threads on server side

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

Good morning/evening,

I´m implementing a long pooling between client-server by ajax-java. And the long polling works properly on the client side, and every 30 seconds a new connection is throw and the previous one is aborted. But the problem is that in the server side all those request/threads keep alive until we have something to return to the client. But like I said the client maybe is not listening anymore. Here some code:

Client:

```
     // Long Polling (Recommened Technique - Creates An Open  Connection To Server ∴ Fast)
  (function poll(){
    var tenantName = $("#tenantName").val();
    $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
    url: "url",
    success: function(data){
        if (data === true) {
            bootbox.alert("Page has been modify <a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='reload()'>reload</a>");
        }
     }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 60000 });
})();
```

Server:

```
       /**
 * @return
 */
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Boolean getSubStepStatus(@RequestParam("subStep") String subStep,
                                @RequestParam("tenantId") String tenantId) {
    if (!isInStep(subStep, tenantId)) {
        tenantsInStep.get(subStep).add(tenantId);
    }
    while (true) {
        String modifierTenantId = stepModifyByTenant.get(subStep);
        if (modifierTenantId != null && !modifierTenantId.equals(tenantId) && !isInStep(subStep, tenantId)) {
            tenantsInStep.get(subStep).remove(tenantId);
            return true;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Problem like I said all threads are growing and growing in the server side every 30 seconds, what I´m doing wrong using this technique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Is not the way to do long polling in Java. The way to do it is to kick the request into async mode, register a listener, and give up the worker thread.

Comment: the request is async. And if you´re suggesting to release the request thread, and send back to the client, how do you avoid the client to send another request. The concept of long polling it´s keep request channel open until there´s something to inform or the timeout pass.

Comment: No, just because you make the request from AJAX doesn't put the servlet request into async mode, you have to actually call [ServletRequest.html#startAsync](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#startAsync(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)). No, I didn't suggest releasing the request thread and sending a response to the client. I did suggest releasing the request thread, putting it into async mode and registering a listener which is the proper way to implement server side push in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using SpringMVC and I assume that the web application is running in a servlet engine (e.g. Tomcat or Jetty).

When processing a request, the server cannot detect whether a client is still listening, unless it is trying to send response data ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962196/detecting-client-disconnect-in-tomcat-servlet)). Your controller code executes a possibly infinite loop (which is a bad idea by itself). As long as this loop is running, no response data is sent, therefore the controller will continue to loop, even if the client has already disconnected.

If you want to keep the current design, an easy fix would be to prevent infinite looping, i.e. break after a set number of iterations or elapsed time and send `false` as response. The client would then have to reconnect to start a new polling cycle.

Comment: The client, abort the request and create a new one every 30 seconds. Problem is that server keeps the old request, until there´re something to tell. I´m just following long polling technique as I read in all tutorials.

Comment: As I said in my answer, the server _cannot_ detect that the client aborted the request until it actually tries to send data to the client. As long as the request processing thread is trapped in the loop it will not attempt to send data to the client, therefore the request threads just keep running until it can exit the loop, attempts to send true to the client and only then realizes the client has disconnected.

Comment: it´s hard to believe that httpServletResponse dont have a boolean method as isRequestAlive or something like that

Comment: Then look at it yourself : [HttpServletResponse](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) and [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html). There is also a blog post from the spring team on long polling with mvc [here](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/14/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-adding-long-polling-to-an-existing-web-application), which may help you.

Comment: I already did, that´s why I was complaining. Maybe was not clear enough XD. Thanks for the spring blog