Check if client connection is alive tomcat9?
Let say we have a spring web application called Client and another spring web application called Server and both are deployed on tomcat9, client is making a request to server and server is now processing the req, in between client have closed the connection and I want to cancel the in process req, Is there any way I can get the client connection from httpservletRequest and check if conn is still alive and can kill the processing thread somehow?

I believe that the correct answer is "you can't" - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962196

The solution might be to establish a web socket, and run an application protocol over that where the server polls the client to see if it is still there.  At the socket level, one party can only detect that the other party has disconnected when they perform a read or write on the socket.  With classic HTTP, that is only going to happen when the server attempts to send the HTTP response.  (TCP-IP keep-alives don't help.  The server still needs to read or write to detect that the connection has been lost.)
